# Как разбить массив на шаги?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как разбить массив на шаги?

В зависимости от значения `step` нужно разбить массив на шаги.

Если `step = 3` , то как `result` превратить массив

из такого `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` в такой `[0, 4, 8]` ?

*Значения в массиве могут быть любые, шаги в данном случае это их позиция!*

```js
let step = 3; // изменяемый
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; // изменяемый и значения могут быть любые
let result = [];
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  result.push(arr[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+= step)

Comment: @Valera Kvip, а как сделать полный массив, тоесть там где пропуск просто пустая строка?

Comment: вопрос не понял.

Comment: @Valera Kvip, тоесть я про такой имел виду `[0, '', '', '', 4, '', '', '', 8, '']`

Comment: Понял, сделай как тебе ответил @Aziz Umarov только добавь условие else  и вставляй пустую строку

Comment: `arr.map((e, i) => i % (step + 1) === 0 ? e : '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для фильтрации массивов имеется `Array.filter`

```js
let skip = 3; 
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; 

let result = arr.filter((v,idx) => idx%(skip+1) == 0);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Отвечай по чаще. Обожаю твои ответы где ничего не понятно, но выглядит эффектно. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

так посмотрите

```js
let step = 3; // изменяемый
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; // изменяемый и значения могут быть любые
let result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if (i%(step + 1) == 0) {
    result.push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

или из комментариев выше

```js
let step = 3; // изменяемый
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; // изменяемый и значения могут быть любые
let result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if (i%(step + 1) == 0) {
    result.push(arr[i]);
  } else {
    result.push('');
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

или из комментов ниже

```js
let step = 3; // изменяемый
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; // изменяемый и значения могут быть любые
let result = [];

for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
  if ((i - 1)%(step + 1) == 0) {
    result.push(arr[i]);
  } else {
    result.push('');
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: а как можно изменить данный код чтобы начинать со второго элемента? Тоесть выводе должно быть `[1, 5, 9]`

Comment: сек сейчас добавлю

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

```js
let step = 3; // изменяемый
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; // изменяемый и значения могут быть любые
let result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += step+1){
    result.push(arr[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```